# Unable to start Abaqus CAE 2021, ImportError: No module named _ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes, abaqus

I'm trying to run the student version of Abaqus 2021 (a FEA software package) on my computer, which involves an internal **init**.py file when starting up the program. However, I run into this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SMAPyaModules\SMAPyaDriverPy.m\src\cae.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "SMAPython\SMAPytLibPy.m\src\site.py", line 120, in _numpyHook
    d = set()
  File "SMAPyrModules\SMAPyrUtiPy.m\src\uti.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "SMAPython\SMAPytLibPy.m\src\site.py", line 120, in _numpyHook
    d = set()
  File "SMAPyrModules\SMAPyrUtiPy.m\src\utiinternal.py", line 60, in <module>
  File "SMAPython\SMAPytLibPy.m\src\site.py", line 120, in _numpyHook
    d = set()
  File "SMAPyrModules\SMAPyrUtiPy.m\src\uticty.py", line 99, in <module>
  File "SMAPython\SMAPytLibPy.m\src\site.py", line 120, in _numpyHook
    d = set()
  File "C:\SIMULIA_2021\CAE\2021SE\win_b64\tools\SMApy\python2.7\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  File "SMAPython\SMAPytLibPy.m\src\site.py", line 120, in _numpyHook
    d = set()
ImportError: No module named _ctypes
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here's the section of code called out in this error:

```
"""create and manipulate C data types in Python"""

import os as _os, sys as _sys

__version__ = "1.1.0"

from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
from _ctypes import _Pointer
from _ctypes import CFuncPtr as _CFuncPtr
from _ctypes import __version__ as _ctypes_version
from _ctypes import RTLD_LOCAL, RTLD_GLOBAL
from _ctypes import ArgumentError
```

It seems from an online search I must get libffi-dev into this internal Abaqus version of Python 2.7 for this code to work. Why I need to do that or how it's done is where I'm stuck at right now!

I've tried reinstalling a different version of Abaqus (this happens with the 2021 and 2022 versions). I want to try installing libffi-dev into this internal Abaqus Python 2.7, but I'm not sure how to do that. On other stackoverflow questions, it has been recommended to use

`sudo apt install libffi-dev`

but as I understand it this command only works on Linux machines, while I have a Windows. When I try to use

`pip install libffi-dev`

on my own version of Python 3.10, I get:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libffi-dev (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libffi-dev
```